# Android /data/data/(packageName)/databases not created

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working an existing SQLite database, I've looked at most tutorials for it, and I had it working for a brief time. Now I am receiving an error while I am copying the database. Long story short, the /data/data/(packageName)/databases is non-existent. I added the folder using the DDMS File Explorer on my emulator and it worked. What would cause the /databases folder to not be created?

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    InputStream myInput = dbContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
    String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're adapting [this solution](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/). Are you calling `createDataBase()` (which creates an empty database along with the `databases` directory) before calling `copyDataBase()`?

Comment: You might consider switching to `SQLiteAssetHelper` rather than rolling your own: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It might Help You

[Link 1](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

[Example 2 This will Help you definitely](https://gist.github.com/1271795)